# Swiper Js Slider Reveal Next Slider Partially

Tags: frontend, slider, swiper.js

I'm creating a slider using Swiper JS which reveals the next slider partially as following

[image: 1]

However it's work great until end of original slides and when the loop mode enabled duplicate slides start next slide is disapear and appear on next one

Following is what I tried so far in JS Fiddle:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Swiper demo</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
  <!-- Link Swiper's CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css" />

</head>

<body>
  <!-- Swiper -->
  <div class="swiper mySwiper">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        
        <div>
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
        </div>
        
        <div>
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum id, velit, voluptatem quis quisquam quas rem, ea, quia iusto tempore animi alias. Natus, voluptas accusantium.
                  </p>
        </div>
        
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        
        <div>
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit tempora perspiciatis ratione excepturi labore, expedita eos quis sequi consequuntur, doloremque odio soluta fugit, ut sed?</p>
        </div>
        
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        
        <div>
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
        </div>
        
        <div>
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum id, velit, voluptatem quis quisquam quas rem, ea, quia iusto tempore animi alias. Natus, voluptas accusantium.
                  </p>
        </div>
        
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        
        <div>
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit tempora perspiciatis ratione excepturi labore, expedita eos quis sequi consequuntur, doloremque odio soluta fugit, ut sed?</p>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  </div>

  <!-- Swiper JS -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

```
.swiper-slide{
  display:flex !important;
}

.swiper-slide div{
  width:calc(50% - 25px);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.swiper-slide div:nth-child(2){
  padding-left: 25px;
}

.swiper-slide div:nth-child(2) p {
 max-width:200px;
}

img{
  width:100%;
}
.mySwiper{
  padding-right: 100px !important;
}
```

```
    var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
        loop:true,
      navigation: {
        nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
        prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
      },
    });
```